# How to add route guards to a MEVN stack authentication app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am attempting to repurpose a simple Vue.js authentication app that I found on GitHub, in order to enable route guards. The app is built on a MEVN stack (MongoDB, Express, Vue.js, Node) and is based directly on the follow GitHub repo: https://github.com/ArjunAranetaCodes/MoreCodes-Youtube/tree/master/mevn-mongodb-login-reg. The app is missing route guards to prevent the user from logging out after refreshing, while also keeping the user logged in after clicking the back arrow in the browser. To resolve this, I attempted to reconfigure the route page (routes/index.js) as the following:

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import Profile from '@/components/Profile'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Register',
      component: Register
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = localStorage.usertoken
  const decoded = jwtDecode(token)
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  return {
    email: decoded.email,
    password: decoded.password
  }
  if (requiresAuth && !email && !password) next('Login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && email && password) next('Profile')
  else next()
})
export default router
```

As you can see, I added a meta condition to the `profile` route called `requiresAuth` and set it to true. I then added a `.beforeEach` function with a conditional that compares the decoded email and password with the state of `requiresAuth`. The following should theoretically enable the user to stay logged into the profile even after refreshing:

```
  if (requiresAuth && !email && !password) next('Login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && email && password) next('Profile')
  else next()
```

...but nothing shows up on the screen, while I am continually getting console warnings (not errors) that `email and password are not defined`. Any recommendations on how to implement route guards for this MEVN application? Thanks!

Firebase example

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('profile')
  else next()
})
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                <form v-on:submit.prevent="login">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'
import EventBus from './EventBus'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    login () {
      axios.post('users/login', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }).then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
        router.push({ name: 'Profile' })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      this.emitMethod()
    },
    emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `email` and `password` *are* not defined. First, try to resolve that. You might also want to prevent an indefinite loop.

Comment: I'm not sure how to define email and password in the router page. See the above Firebase example that I added to my question. With Firebase, I would normally be able to add a variable called ```currentUser``` based on the ```firebase.auth().currentUser```. However, with the MEVN stack I am not sure how to set up the router page in order to identify the ```currentUser```and create a conditional that compares the currentUser with the state of ```requiresAuth```. Is there a way to pull the ```currentUser``` into the router page?

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? Authorization for every page? And you also want to validate the login/password? And you also want a remember-me function? And you also want to store the user *and the password* and then import it again? Those are different things...

Comment: I want the user to stay logged in even after refreshing the page. Currently, the user gets logged out after refreshing. In previous demos that I have built with Firebase, the above Firebase .beforeEach function enables the user to stay logged in even after refreshing. I want to enable something similar in a MEVN stack router page.

Comment: And how does the user get logged in? Do you get a session ID somehow? Or how do you store the authentication in the front-end? Do you just store the username and password and send it always along?

Comment: See ```Login.vue``` above. Authentication is passed as a token to Login.vue as a response from ```routes/Users.js``` and then stored in localStorage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199539/discussion-between-js-is-awesome18-and-ssc-hrep3).